# BizTalk WCF SQL adapter typed procedure for inserting xml escape chracters?

Tags: biztalk

we are using the WCF SQL adapter to log the message to database, but the message itself has several characters that need to be escaped in xml, i.e. my message looks like this 'abc&d', then if i use the typed store procedure I will have problem. Is there any workaround? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your data source to provide valid xml. There isn't a workaround that I'm aware of.

FYI: I've also found our sql server can produce invalid xml. Specifically it does not escape some unprintable characters. We had problems in the opposite direction. We were consuming output from a stored procedure into BizTalk.